# Blazor server High CPU Usage

Tags: windows, blazor-server-side, cpu-usage, visual-studio-2022, syncfusion-blazor

Am experiencing a serious issue on cpu usage on blazor web app,the app is small.CPU usage is a high as 93%.I need some Assist on the cause of this high usage.Am using syncfusion components.This is happening when app is not even running.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add `Startup.cs` page, if you are using `.Net6` add `Program.cs`, so we can check the pipeline!

Answer (score 0):

I Think it's not a problem of blazor, it's VS2022, you specific when the app it's not runing, i experienced something similar and just change my project to VS 2019 and solved my problem, unfortunately, vs2022 it's not optimized for some CPUs, and you have the usage of the cpu on your ide, not the services!